# Blender does not recognize Alembic file from Houdini

Tags: import, alembic

im pretty new to Houdini but a Blender user for almost 2 years now.

I made a Fluid Simulation in Houdini, exported the deforming mesh as an alembic file, but whenever i try to Import it to blender, the file is nowhere to select. Blender does not recognize it.

I've checked the Export Settings in Houdini, and i think they're correct.

Has anybody ever had a similar Problem and hopefully a solution? 
Couldn't find helpful material for this Problem online.

Thanks a lot in Advance

Comment: How did you "import" it. Can you upload a small .abc? (Maybe just the first 2 frames.) I have succeded doing exactly what you describe, although with troubles as wel.

Comment: Thanks for the quick Response! 

Are there multiple ways to Import? 

File -> Import -> Alembic (.abc) is how i tried, but as mentioned, i see an alembic file on my Desktop, yet it doesnt Show up in the Import window in blender, there's Nothing to Import

Also just the 2 Frames didn't do anything for me  =/  

It's 80 Frames Long.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. I meant to ask if you could **upload** *your abc file* so I can download and try it =)

Answer (score 2):

blender does not see .abc files from houdini, so in houdini you have to put the name of your project when exporting and after the name type .abc as the name